# how can i get only month number and year randomly without time in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How can I generate a random date that only has the number of the month and the year in a random way that comes in this EXAMPLE format "05/23" in c #?

Comment: Pick a random number in the year range you want. Pick a random number in the range [1, 12] for the month. Put them together in a string, e.g. `var d = $"{m:D2}/{y:D2}";`. But that is a string, not a date. You could make a new DateTime with the day set to, say, 1, if you need a DateTime, and just ignore the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int month = rnd.Next(1,12);
int year = rnd.Next(2000,2050);

string date = $"{month:D2}/{year:D2}";
```